# Regarding 10GB ISCSI using flex system

Tags: ibm

Currently we want to implement the 10gb ISCSI SAN.

So we are planning to buy the below hardware:

1) IBM flex system enterprise chassis

2) Two X240 nodes with CN4054R 10gb Virtual Fabric Adapter﻿

3) Two IBM Flex System Fabric EN4093R 10Gb Scalable Switch﻿

4) IBM Storwize V3700 with 10Gb iSCSI - FCoE 2 Port Host Interface Card

**My question is ﻿﻿it possible to link EN4093R 10Gb Scalable Switch﻿ with V3700 disk storage using the ﻿Direct Attach Cable(eg:IBM Passive DAC SFP+ Cable).**

Thanks.﻿﻿

Comment: e0594cn, I really hope you get an answer to this, but it's such a specific question that you may have more luck asking your IBM hardware supply person.  While you're waiting, you might want to go back over your past questions and see if any of them have an answer you could accept; people are generally more keen to answer questions for someone who accepts answers.